# Mutating method send to immutable object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This the snippet of code where I get an error:

```
//sourceArray is a NSMutablearray  
NSMutableDictionary *dayOfWeekDictionary= [sourceArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];  
[dayOfWeekDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"isSelected"];//line 2
```

What I’ve come to know from googling is that there is some stuff in assigning immutable object into mutable object.

I get an error at line 2. Any suggestions?

Comment: i have tried NSMutableDictionary *dayOfWeekDictionar y= [NSMutableArray ArrayWithArray:[sourceArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]];,still application crashing...

Comment: How does the dayOfWeekDictionary end up in the soruceArray? One common issue is that if you read if from user defaults, then even if you originally wrote a mutable dictionary, it will be read back from defaults as an immutable one. So when you read it back, convert it to a mutable dictionary as Bavarious suggests below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `[sourceArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]` returns an immutable dictionary, simply assigning it to a variable of type `NSMutableDictionary *` doesn’t automatically convert it to a mutable dictionary. You could write this instead:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dayOfWeekDictionary= [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[sourceArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]];
```

By using `+[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:]`, you get a mutable dictionary based on another dictionary (which can be either mutable or immutable). Note that you do not own this dictionary, hence you don’t have to release it. Also note that this is **not** the same dictionary object as the one stored in the array. If you need both the array and `dayOfWeekDictionary` to be the same dictionary, then you should add a mutable dictionary to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is an instance of `NSMutableDictionary` in `[sourceArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]`?

I suggest placing a break point at line 2 and inspecting the content of `dayOfWeekDictionary`.

AND

In your comment, you set an instance of `NSMutableArray` into the variable `dayOfWeekDictionary` of type `NSMutableDictionary`, if you try to call `[dayOfWeekDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"isSelected"];` the application will crash with an `unrecognized selector sent to instance`.